# Best way to show two forms with one action in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Leaded by DRY principle, which is the best way to show two child forms with one action in Delphi.
My parent form has two buttons for two child forms. I have TActionList where TAction is added with OnExecute event. What is the best way this two buttons for child forms to use one action to open them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two actions that share the same `OnExecute` event handler. Use the `Sender` parameter of that event handler to discriminate:

```
procedure TMainForm.acShowFormExecute(Sender: TAction);
begin
  if Sender=acShowForm1 then
    Form1.Show
  else if Sender=acShowForm2 then
    Form2.Show
  else
    raise ESomeInternalExceptionClass.Create('Unexpected action');
end;
```

You need to use two actions because, for instance, your two buttons will have different captions.

It is a somewhat moot whether or not sharing `OnExecute` event handlers is worth it for this particular example. If you had distinct event handlers that would look like:

```
procedure TMainForm.acShowForm1Execute(Sender: TAction);
begin
  Form1.Show;
end;

procedure TMainForm.acShowForm2Execute(Sender: TAction);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Then again, if you need to do extra work in your event handler, the balance tips back the other way:

```
procedure TMainForm.acShowFormExecute(Sender: TAction);
var
  FormClass: TMyChildFormClass;
  Form: TTMyChildForm;
begin
  if Sender=acShowForm1 then
    FormClass := TForm1
  else if Sender=acShowForm2 then
    FormClass := TForm2
  else
    raise ESomeInternalExceptionClass.Create('Unexpected action');

  Form := FormClass.Create(GetParam1, GetParam2);
  try
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;      
end;
```

Pretty much as soon as the body of the event handler consists of more than a single liner, then I'd say it was worthwhile sharing the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It can have 1 action and 2 different captions for the buttons if you leave action caption property blank and modify only button caption.

Comment: That's interesting, I did not know that. Of course, then you can't discriminate!

Comment: You can modify button caption after the action is set whether its caption blank or not. But that defits the pursupse of the action. It has more important properties.